# Variant of Nakayama's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> I am trying to prove that if $M$ is an $R$-module, with $R$ complete w.r.t. an ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and $M$ is separated ($\cap_k \mathfrak{m}^k M=0$) and the images of $m_1,\dots,m_n$ generate $M/\mathfrak{m} M$, then $m_1,\dots,m_n$ generate $M$.

This appears as Exercise 7.2 in *Eisenbud*'s *Commutative Algebra* text.

I am pretty stuck and would appreciate some hints.

Comment: This is Theorem 8.4 from Matsumura, CRT.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, by the way. I was able to figure it out from your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Set $N=\langle m_1,\dots,m_n\rangle$. We have $M=\mathfrak mM+N=\mathfrak m(\mathfrak mM+N)+N=\mathfrak m^2M+N$, and so on.